# Что не так с моим кодом? Скажите ппжпжпжпп

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Написал код, а компилятор говорит что я не прав.

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: Может быть, компилятору не нравится, что вы имеете что-то против Артурика и прячете ругань в скриншоте.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Ну можно хоть немного думать?!

И подчеркнуто, и сказано...

Куда вы тут пытаетесь что-то ввести?

```
cout >> i >> ;
```

Ну стыдно же такие вопросы задавать!